# How to query data from laravel relationship using vue.js? [ laravel, vue ]

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to query my data in relationship using vue.js and still, I cant make it work.
Also, I got an errors like below.

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

When I changed my code like this

```
<span v-for="user in users">
    {{ user.address.city }}
</span>
```

And in my Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $query = Customers::with('address')
                    ->with('purchases')
                    ->paginate(10);
    return CustomersResource::collection($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div v-for="user in users">
    <span v-if="user.address && user.address.name">{{ user.address.name }}</span>
</div>
```

Always check if your object exists before accessing it.

Comment: here my `console.log(res)`

{
"id": 1,
"name": "Edwina Stark II",
"phone": "1-579-682-1998 x579",
"created_at": "2019-08-15 03:40:24",
"updated_at": "2019-08-15 03:40:24",
"address": {
"id": 1,
"customer_id": 1,
"address": "7822 Ziemann Points Suite 993\nEast Odessa, NC 54867-8606",
"city": "Ollieville",
"created_at": "2019-08-15 03:40:30",
"updated_at": "2019-08-15 03:40:30"
}

why i cant access it?

Comment: Because the object inside of the `address` object has no name

Comment: its still does same thing, when i change to `user.address.city`

Answer (score 0):

Add withDefault after your relationship.

```
public function address(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Address','user_id','id')->withDefault([
    'name' => '-'
    ]);
}
```

There is existing code that depends on the result of any Eloquent relationship to either be **null**, a Model instance, or a **Collection** of **Model** instances. However, the current functionality of the **withDefault()** method opens up the potential for returning an object that is not one of those three expected values.

Comment: Can you show your model? or print_r($query) and edit your answer?

Comment: `// Customer Model`
`
  public function address()
    {
     return $this->hasOne(CustomersAddress::class, 'customer_id');
    }

    public function purchases()
    {
     return $this->hasMany(CustomersPurchase::class, 'customer_id');
    }
`

Comment: public function address() { return $this->hasOne(CustomersAddress::class, 'customer_id')->withDefault(); }

Comment: but, i dont visible anything anything in my page and it dont give any error